# Codemagic: how do I set up integration tests Android Emulator

Tags: flutter, codemagic, widget-test-flutter

Here is how the default configuration for tests looks like:

[image]

In Flutter Drive arguments we can see that there is a target defined

> drive --target=test_driver/main.dart

Flutter documentation on integration tests doesn't mention creating this file. So this folder with the respective file is missing in my project, which logically results into fail:

> Target file "test_driver/main.dart" not found.

Here are the logs:

```
> flutter devices
3 connected devices:

Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
macOS (desktop)                    • macos         • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64
Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114
> flutter -d emulator-5554 drive --target=test_driver/main.dart
Target file "test_driver/main.dart" not found.
```

The documentation on how to write [integration tests](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) only mentions `test_driver` when testing web.

Apparently I am either missing stuff in my project or I need to configure codemagic workflow differently.

There is a bit information here https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-testing/testing/ for yaml configuration. Should i switch to yaml config, or can it be done from CodeMagic UI?

**UPDATE:**
After I have change the configuration as mentioned in the answers to this:

[image]

The logs are now:

> Test file not found: > /Users/builder/clone/test_driver/app_test_test.dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach per [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction#5-run-the-integration-test) is to use:

```
flutter test integration_test
```

Thus, in the arguments section in Codemagic, just add `test integration_test`.

Answer (score 1):

`test_driver/main.dart` is just a placeholder. Flutter documentation covered this in step [3. Create the test files](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction#3-create-the-test-files)

And in Codemagic you need to specify `drive --target=integration_test/app_test.dart`

Comment: Seems like something is still wrong. 
Could you see the update of my question? Now the log says: `Test file not found:  /Users/builder/clone/test_driver/app_test_test.dart` ...very weird path

Comment: I do have `/integration_test/app_test.dart`in my project